# Including a module more than once

Tags: module, fortran

Suppose I have a module which defines some basic constants such as

```
integer, parameter :: i8 = selected_int_kind(8)
```

If I include this in my main program and I also include a module which does some other things (call this module `functions`) but `functions` also `use`s `constants`, then am I essentially including `constants` twice in my main program?

If so, is this bad? Can it be dangerous at all to include a module too many times in a program?

Comment: No, it is fine to do this. All you are doing with the `use` statements is bringing variables into a subprograms scope. It is not like declaring variables each time they are `use`'d. The only thing to be wary of are *circular dependencies*, where module `A` uses module `B` and module `B` uses module `A`. This is not allowed.

Comment: thanks, make this an answer so i can give you a check mark!

Comment: Thanks, I have done and added a bit more information as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, it is fine to do this. All you are doing with the `use` statement is providing access to the variables and functions defined in your module via *use association*. It is not like declaring variables each time they are `use`'d (they are in fact redeclared however).

The only thing to be wary of are *circular dependencies*, where module `A` uses module `B` and module `B` uses module `A`. This is not allowed.

**Edit:** From Metcalf *et al*. Fortran 95/2003 explained, pg. 72:

> A module may contain `use` statements that access other modules. It must not access itself directly or indirectly through a chain of `use` statements, for example `a` accessing `b` and `b` accessing `a`.

Whilst this quote doesn't directly answer your question, it reiterates that really the only thing you can't do is have a circular dependency. So the following is perfectly valid:

```
module one_def
  implicit none
  integer, parameter :: one=1
end module one_def

module two_def
  use one_def, only : one
  implicit none
  integer, parameter :: two=one+one
end module two_def

program test
  use one_def, only : one
  use two_def, only : two
  implicit none

  print*, two == one+one ! This prints .True.

end program
```